# Magento - get attribute text from deleted configurable-product in orderemail

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have a question about getting the of an attribute from a configurable-product. Cause we cleaned up our catalog a bit and delete some products including a few configurable products with their associated products, we can't send any emails with orders which have those deleted products associated. In general we show the attribute texts from the configurable product in the email. In my example I have a configurable product with the attribute size_attribute. The product in the order has for example the value 20x20cm.

Normally I get the attribute value like this:

**../template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml**

```
$_simple = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadbyAttribute('sku',$_item->getSku());

$attr = $_simple->getResource()->getAttribute('size_attribute');
$attribute_code = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->load($attr->getAttributeId())->getAttributeCode();

$attribute_text = $_simple->getAttributeText($attribute_code)
```

Now I have the problem that this line will fail cause the product does not exist anymore in our database:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadbyAttribute('sku',$_item->getSku())
```

I know that Magento copy all the information of each orderitem in a separate table which is not getting touched when deleting products from catalog.

Unfortunately the most solutions which I read across the internet start with the above line.

So is there a way to get the attribute text in another way?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to load a product which has been deleted, obviously.

Problem here was caused by wrong implementation in the first place, when dealing with orders, data should not be fetched from products, since the attribute values can change. Instead, new `sales/quote_item` attribute should be created where value from product will be copied during add-to-cart process (probably on `sales_quote_item_set_product` event).